# Global optimisation of function with many parameters (~40) and local minima in Python

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, minimization

Does anyone have some experience with global optimization problems for complex objective functions with multiple local minima and many parameters? For me, CPU time is less of a constraint but actually finding the global minimum is the most important. So far I have tried Scipy 'dual_annealing' (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.dual_annealing.html) but after running on 32 cores for 24 hours no global minimum was found (perhaps I need to fine-tune this minimizer a bit more or provide stronger bounds?). Are there any other minimization routines that could be more suited to this application?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: How can you check a minimum is local and not global? How are you certain a minimum is global? Just this alone can be very difficult unless your problems is part of a (lucky) subset, like lineair and/or convex

Comment: Find a GPU-supporting genetic-algorithm library and combine its mutation amplitude with a simulated-annealing algorithm (to restart the diversity multiple times) and have a big DNA population. With a custom CUDA-accelerated GA+SA library and 2 low-end graphics cards (192 CUDA pipelines each), it paints Mona-Lisa from 256 circles (1024 parameters for X,Y, color and radius) in 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Hyperparameter optimizer frameworks that you can try.

- [Optuna](https://github.com/optuna/optuna)
- [microsoft nni](https://github.com/microsoft/nni)
- [Nevergrad](https://github.com/facebookresearch/nevergrad)

Answer (score 0):

With 40+ parameters is going to be a very tough one, especially if you want to be reasonably certain that you located the global minimum (not that any algorithm will be able to tell you that anyway)… I had good results with Dual Annealing from SciPy, albeit on lower-dimensional problems.

But still, 24 hours? How expensive is your objective function to evaluate? Do you have the analytical gradient available? I guess the answer is “no”, but if you do there may be quite a few promising techniques to try. Are you specifying bounds for your parameters?

Have you looked at NLopt (https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/NLopt_Algorithms/)? In the past I had surprisingly good results on larger problems using the Controlled Random Search (CRS) algorithm, but your mileage may vary.